# What’s probability of 2 people with same 5 letters in their first name but different results

Tags: probability, statistics, education

What is the probability of 2 people meeting with the same 5 letters in their first name but different result name. my name is Denny, my friend’s name is Ynden. Same 5 letters different result.

Comment: It will depend on how many of each letter, and also on how many people in all are looked at to see if there is a match.

Comment: Names are not words with random letters. So we won't be able to answer this. I think there are not many such cases anyway that a name is an anagram of another. In Germany, an example would be "Erna" vs "Arne"

Comment: Might be an interesting programming challenge, assuming one had a list of "valid" first names.